# Autocomplete with CouchDB and now.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, autocomplete, couchdb

I'd like to enable autocomplete on some text fields and don't really know the best strategy to go with. All data is stored in CouchDB and I have some views which return the id and the key with the names for autocompletion. I read about the [start key and end key solution](http://blog.couchbase.com/typeahead-search-couchdb) and I'd like to use this with now.js. How would that look like?

Is that the right solution to go with or should I rather synchronize with redis or memcache? Or fill a Trie with the list? Or HTMl5 local storage?

The data is used on the main page, so it's queried very often, but the set is not very large, maybe up to 500 entries, changing approx. once per week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used now.js autocomplete with CouchDB Typeahead Search and the results were very good. Didn't want to install another library (YUI).

Answer (score 0):

500 entries is not too large in my opinion. You can do this for a start: YUI autocomplete module on the front end. Upon page load, retrieve the data once from the server over a REST api and initialize autocomplete data structures for each of the fields needing it.

For larger data sets, you can still use YUI autocomplete widget but the data will come from server upon each keystroke. On the server, you can pre-build a ternary search tree based index (once a week) and serve it using a web service, taking a partly-typed string and returning a fixed maximum list of matches as output. Check out the finance symbol autocompletion on yahoo finance.

The advantage of the server based method is that the performance is snappy regardless of the corpus (data) size. But for optimal memory usage you will only want to store a finite list of matches in the nodes of the tree. Using the first method, where the YUI autocomplete module stores and indexes the data, you can see all matches for an input, but the response can be a bit slower.